# Abstract Algebra Order of Group Help

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am doing a group writing project on the Heisenberg Group and one of the things we have to find if the order of the group is finite or infinite. How do I begin to find the order of a group? I am confused on where to start because my book doesn't go into any detail on how to find the order of a group.

Comment: It might be a good place to start with the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group).

Comment: @T.Bongers I think the relevant article is [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_a_group)

Answer (score 1):

The order of a group is the number of elements it has. For example, the cyclic group with three elements has order $3$ (finite order), but the group of integers under addition has infinite order.

So: how is the Heisenberg Group defined? Does it have infinitely many elements or finitely many elements?

Comment: The Heisenberg Group is defined under matrix multiplication. So it would have infinitely many elements?

Comment: The group operation isn't relevant here, just the set of elements. What are the elements of the Heisenberg Group?

Comment: I am getting confused on what the elements are. Would they be a,b,c or the set of subgroups?

Comment: A group is a set together with a binary operation. The elements are the things in the set! In the case of the Heisenberg Group, an element will be a matrix.